# trying to figure out how this for loop is working

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is a list with numbers and another list with the frequency.

```
age = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
frequency = [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

now I have to create another list containing the data from list age at the respected frequencies specified by the frequency list

```
S = [19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25]
```

i saw the code to do this online

```
def interquartile(arr,freq,n):
    for i,j in zip(arr,freq):
        for k in range(j):
            s.append(i)
   
    print('This is S',s)
interquartile(age,frequency,7)
```

but i do not understand what is happening in the first and second for loop

Comment: What don't you understand about them? Do you know what `zip()` and `range()` do?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you already read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip()` creates a tuple of two lists:

```
list(zip(age,frequency))
[(19, 2), (20, 1), (21, 1), (22, 3), (23, 2), (24, 1), (25, 1)]
```

So in the first loop, `i` and `j` are the first items of each `age` and `frequency`.

```
age = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
frequency = [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

The second loop will loop `j` times, means it will loop `2` times.

Each loop, `i` will be appended to the list `s`.

```
for i,j in zip(arr,freq):
    # i = 19
    # j = 2
    for k in range(j):
        s.append(i)
```

After one loop, the list looks like this:

```
s = [19, 19]
```

After another loop, it looks like this:

```
s = [19, 19, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a simple one liner that accomplishes what you're looking for you can use a list comprehension like this as long as the length of the two lists are the same:

```
data = [num for i, num in enumerate(age) for j in range(frequency[i])]
```

The first loop `for i, num in enumerate(age)` loops through the list of ages and gives the index `i` and the value of `age` at that index.

The second loop `for j in range(frequency[i])` will loop for the value at `frequency[i]`.

All together, you are inserting the current number by the number of times denoted by the frequency list.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this:
When you call the function interquartile(age, frequency, 7), you're calling this function:

```
interquartile(arr,freq,n)
```

age became your input arr,

frequency became your input freq,

n (7 in this case is useless, you're not using it anywhere).

In this for loop, you're taking an element of arr and an element of freq into i and j respectively:

```
for i,j in zip(arr,freq):
```

In this below loop, you're running the loop **j** number of times. that is 1, 2, or 3 times depending on the value in frequency.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp
for more info on zip().

```
    for k in range(j):
```

When you append the value, j number of times, the value from age gets appended to list s.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code needs some improvement. n is not needed and also s must be declared before appending elements to it. The correct code is:

```
def interquartile(arr,freq):
    s=[]
    for i,j in zip(arr,freq):
        for k in range(j):
            s.append(i)
    print('This is S',s)

interquartile(age,frequency)
```

The above code takes 2 lists (possibly with same length, even though it is not mentioned) and creates pairs of elements (i,j) in same position of each list with zip. Then using range(j) it repeats j times the element i, and adds them to s, giving the desired output, when process finishes.

Answer (score 0):

In first for loop you are getting the values from both age and frequency like 19 2
In the second for loop you iterate the loop for j(2) times and append 19 twice into s list.

use print statements after each for loop for better understanding.